# My email to text sent to vtext.com stopped working

Tags: email, text, gateway

I have been sending emails (through gmail accounts and gmail smtp server) to text gateways of various wireless providers and they worked pretty well for years until this year. The messages stopped working for all verizon numbers a few months ago. I didn't receive any feedback as to why it stopped working. It is as if the email was sent successfully and then silently swallowed by vtext.com. I tried to limit the number of recipients per email but it didn't help. I did a lot of searches online but could not find a sure reason what has been changed. I started to suspect that my ip or domain has been blacklisted by verizon, but I have no way to contact verizon support about its gateway policy and whether my suspicion is true. The customer support of the wireless department said he knew nothing about vtext.com and thus could not help. All my messages are sports team related (inclement weather, etc.) and they are not spams.

I'd really appreciate any help on finding out the true reason this stopped working, and who/where I can contact to resolve this. This is very important for my web site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[This is why...](https://www.verizonwireless.com/businessportals/support/faqs/TXTmessaging/faq_vtext_website.html)

It's all about revenue. If you were using Vtext, good chance you have been blocked by Verizon and they want you to purchase enterprise services. Happened to my company today and this has been a critical part of our system to page work orders out to field technicians that service medical equipment. Verizon has affected patient care, and seem to not care when I asked if they can unblock us just so we can make a strategic transition.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same thing recently. When I called care they told me vtext is being decommissioned in favor of messaging+, which to my knowledge doesn't have an email gateway.  Apprently your region and mine are gone and the plan is to have all vtext shut down by end of 2016.

Currently looking in to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this, too. However, I've found that the mms gateway still works.

`<phone_number>@vzwpix.com`